# Regex split by capturing parentheses - browser support :

Tags: javascript, regex, cross-browser

Looking at this sample :

```
>'1,2,3,4,5'.split(/,/)
```

Result : `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`

But looking at this sample :

```
>'1,2,3,4,5'.split(/(,)/)
```

Result : `["1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5"]`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) :

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array. **However, not all browsers support this
>   capability.**

**Question :**

Where can I find the list of browsers ( and versions) which supports that feature.

mdn doesn't expose that info.

Comment: you should've posted what browser you used in this example

Comment: i think it does. i mean i can't seem to help you. but your question is about browser support.

Comment: I don't have a list for you, but RegexBuddy reports that MS Internet Explorer will not add the contents in capturing groups to the resulting array *if it's being run in "Quirks Mode"*. So Internet Explorer 5 would be one member of that list.

Comment: @closer - find a tool ?? hahaha

Comment: This behaviour is in the ECMA 5.1 specification, so the problem here is how well the browsers follow the specs in its implementation.

Comment: Must-read: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split and maybe http://xregexp.com/cross_browser/

Comment: @Bergi You're the man (p.s. ie11 does support /()/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Browser

#### Internet Explorer

From the blog of [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) and [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/cross_browser/) website, it is confirmed that the correct behavior (inclusion of text captured by capturing groups in the result array) is **not** implemented up to **Internet Explorer 8**.

I have independently confirmed this result on browserstack, and further confirmed that the behavior of `String.split` when a regex with capturing group is supplied is correctly implemented for Internet Explorer only from **version 10** onwards.

Below are links to relevant screenshots:

- [Screenshot of Windows 7 IE 8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS6mz.png)
- [Screenshot of Windows 7 IE 9.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IANiX.png)
- [Screenshot of Windows 7 IE 10.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpTXe.png)
- [Screenshot of Windows 7 IE 11.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPYeH.png)

### Appendix

Full source code of the test site:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h1>Testing String.split, given regex with capturing group</h1>");

function runTest(num, actual, expected) {
    var equals = true;

    if (actual.length === expected.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
            if (actual[i] !== expected[i]) {
                equals = false;
                break;
            }
        }  
    } else {
        equals = false;
    }

    document.write("<h2>Test " + num + ":</h2>");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode("'" + actual.join("'     '") + "'"));
    document.write(equals ? "<h2>Compliant to ECMA 5.1</h2>" : "<h2>NOT compliant to ECMA 5.1</h2>");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
runTest(1, '1,2,3,4,5'.split(/(,)/), ["1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5"]);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
runTest(2, 'ABCDEF'.split(/()/), ["A", "", "B", "", "C", "", "D", "", "E", "", "F"]);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
runTest(3, 'text<a>text</a>'.split(/<(\/)?([^>]+)>/), ["text", void 0, "a", "text", "/", "a", ""]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Other browsers? Now that pre-11 IE versions have receded, support by other browsers becomes interesting. I created a [New Issue](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/3467) on caniuse.com.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: Well, you can just host the web page somewhere (source is there in the post all along) and run it on free screenshot service.